# Bigquery Error: UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

Tags: google-bigquery

Just wondering if someone could help with the following error:

UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

My query is as below:

```sql
UPDATE `sandbox.sellout` s
SET s.SKU_Label = TRIM(SKU_TEMP.SKU)
FROM (SELECT SKU, Old_SKU FROM `sandbox.ref_sku_temp`) SKU_TEMP
WHERE TRIM(SKU_TEMP.Old_SKU) = TRIM(s.SKU)
```

Comment: The problem is that a given `SKU` in the `sellout` table might match more than one `Old_SKU` in the `ref_sku_temp` table.  Please post sample data.

Comment: Please note that a sample of the original tables with sample data is required in addition to the destination output table sample so we can understand the intent of this query to help you accomplish what is intended.

Answer (score 12):

If a row in the table to be updated joins with more than one row from the FROM clause, then the query generates the following runtime error: UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row.
[Data Manipulation Language Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax).

Answer (score 4):

It occurs because the target table of the BigQuery contains duplicated row(w.r.t you are joining). If a row in the table to be updated joins with more than one row from the FROM clause, then BigQuery returns this error:

**Solution**

- Remove the duplicated rows from the target table and perform the UPDATE/MERGE operation
- Define Primary key in BigQuery target table to avoid data redundancy

Comment: Wait, BigQuery doesn't have a concept of primary key, and will happily permit duplicate records. Why and how is "define primary key in BigQuery target table" a solution?

Comment: One particular thing that comes to mind is for things like incrementally appending to a table using something like DBT and a scheduler. Defining a unique key for merge throws this error when unique keys don't make unique rows and overwriting becomes dangerous/ambiguous.

Comment: Both of the solutions are incorrect. Quoting from BigQuery docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#from_keyword 
"If a row in the table to be updated joins with more than one row from the FROM clause, then the query generates the following runtime error: UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row."

The error happens because of duplicate rows in source table that match with a row in target table.

Answer (score 2):

Add `DISTINCT` to your select statement like this:

```
UPDATE `sandbox.sellout` s
SET s.SKU_Label = TRIM(SKU_TEMP.SKU)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SKU, Old_SKU FROM `sandbox.ref_sku_temp`) SKU_TEMP
WHERE TRIM(SKU_TEMP.Old_SKU) = TRIM(s.SKU)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the duplicate rows in the source table. Please consider removing the the dups and run the query. Or post the sample data here.