# In BigQuery, how can I update rows where a property is null with another row's value if they share the same ID?

Tags: join, google-bigquery, sql-update

I'm trying to use a JOIN to put the address of rows that have the same parcelid, with other rows that have the same parcelid but a NULL address. I am getting an error:

> UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

Here was my attempt:

```
UPDATE portfolioproj2.nashvillehousing.realhousingdata
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL(t1.PropertyAddress,t2.PropertyAddress)
FROM portfolioproj2.nashvillehousing.realhousingdata AS t1
JOIN portfolioproj2.nashvillehousing.realhousingdata AS t2
    ON t1.ParcelID = t2.ParcelID
    AND t1.UniqueID_ <> t2.UniqueID_
WHERE t1.PropertyAddress IS NULL;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bigquery Error: UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504504/bigquery-error-update-merge-must-match-at-most-one-source-row-for-each-target-r)

Answer (score 0):

Would you try below instead ?

```sql
UPDATE `portfolioproj2.nashvillehousing.realhousingdata` t
   SET t.PropertyAddress = s.PropertyAddress
  FROM (
    -- find non-null *PropertyAddress* for each *ParcelID*
    SELECT ParcelID, MAX(PropertyAddress) PropertyAddress 
      FROM `portfolioproj2.nashvillehousing.realhousingdata`
     GROUP BY 1
  ) s
 WHERE t.PropertyAddress IS NULL AND t.ParcelID = s.ParcelID;
```