# How can I update a column in one table based on a match with another table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

SQL in BigQuery - UPDATE must match at most one source row for each target row

I'm trying to write data to the column "vertical" in tableA using data in tableB with the same column name, based on a match between the columns "query" from tableA and "keyword" from tableB. Problem is: tableA has multiple rows with the same match (sample data provided below).

Error message I'm getting is

> UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

This is the query I'm currently running:

```
UPDATE `tableA` AS tA
SET tA.vertical = tB.vertical
FROM `tableB` AS tB
WHERE tA.query = tB.keyword;
```

And those are the samples for the tableA and tableB.

**tableA**

| query | unique_key | vertical |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123456 | null |
| abc | 789abc | null |
| abc | defghi | null |
| def | 5l5p5p | null |
| def | qwertz | null |
| def | m43222 | null |

**tableB**

| keyword | vertical |
| --- | --- |
| abc | planet |
| def | earth |

And this is how I was expecting the tableA to be after running the query:

**Updated tableA**

| query | unique_key | vertical |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123456 | planet |
| abc | 789abc | planet |
| abc | defghi | planet |
| def | 5l5p5p | earth |
| def | qwertz | earth |
| def | m43222 | earth |

Any support is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs [when the relationship between the two tables is 1:n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54785770/12492890), that is, "*tA.query*" is matched with multiple "*tB.keyword*". In order to solve this problem, you need to restrict the relationship to 1:1,

- either by selecting the `DISTINCT` couples of your table B

```
UPDATE `tableA` AS tA
SET tA.vertical = tB.vertical
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT vertical, query FROM `tableB`) AS tB
WHERE tA.query = tB.keyword;
```

- or by selecting the `MIN`/`MAX` of your keyword, given the assumption that such operation would be correct for your output

```
UPDATE `tableA` AS tA
SET tA.vertical = tB.vertical
FROM (SELECT vertical, MIN(query) FROM `tableB` GROUP BY vertical) AS tB
WHERE tA.query = tB.keyword;
```

Comment: Hey lemon, I just tried your approach using `DISTINCT` and got the same error message. Unfortunately your second suggestion using `MIN`/`MAX` would not work, since "_tA.query_" and "_tB.keyword_" are mostly strings.

Comment: Have you double checked relationship between the two tables?

Comment: Yeah, tableA will always have multiple instances of the same string in column "_query_", due to the source of the data, so 1:1 relationships wouldn't work. Or am I missing something from your answer?

Comment: when you do an inner join between tableA and tableB, do you get duplicate tableA.query values?

Comment: Yes, the results of the inner join are not 100% perfect (it's not doing exact matches) but it is showing duplicate tableA.query values.

Comment: That's your problem, now you need to make sure relationship is 1:1, otherwise you'll never be able to do that update, that's it.

Comment: Alright, I will dive deeper into it. Thanks for the support.

Comment: I just went through your suggestion again and realized I was looking at the wrong table (tableA instead of tableB). I now made all `tableB.keyword` values unique and it works. Thanks!