# How do I use UPDATE to update records based on a match or join between tables?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I have two tables. Table A has a column for state, full name, first name, middle name, last name, and status. Table B has a column for full name and status. In table A, there are sometimes multiple rows with the same full name (this is because when the data entrer was unclear about whether a person's name was a first, middle, or last name, they created a row for each permutation. Table B has only one row per person.

Table A looks like this:

```
State | full name | first | middle | last | status
AK | John Smith |  John | | Smith | 1
FL | Mary Darling Ellen White | Mary Darling | Ellen | White |
FL | Mary Darling Ellen White | Mary | Darling Ellen| White |
FL | Mary Darling Ellen White | Mary | Darling| Ellen White |
FL | Argyle Johnson | Argyle | | Johnson | 2
MA | Caleb London | Caleb | | London | 1
```

Table B looks like this:

```
State | Name | Status
FL | Mary Darling Ellen White | 1
FL | Argyle Johnson | 2
```

The goal is to update table 1 such that all the rows with null values in the status column in Table A (in the example above, rows 2-4) are updated with the status value for that person in Table B. In this subset, success would mean that rows 2-4 in Table A are updated with the status 1. In reality Table A has more rows, some of which have name permutations and some of which have a null status, and some of which that have both.

What I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE Table_A

SET status = fl.status

FROM Table_A a

JOIN Table_B fl ON a.full_name = fl.name

WHERE a.State = 'FL';
```

And I got the error "UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row". Presumably this means there is a problem with trying to update the status because of the multiple rows that with the same Full Name in Table A. How can I get around this?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50504504/bigquery-error-update-merge-must-match-at-most-one-source-row-for-each-target-r

Comment: This issue does not occur for SQL server 2014+. I was able to create your example via fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/xgVKYiVE

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
update table_a a set
  a.status = (select b.status
              from table_b b
              where b.state = a.state
                and b.name = a.name
             );
```

or

```
merge into table_a a
  using table_b b
  on     a.state = b.state
     and a.name = b.name
when matched then update set
  a.status = b.status;
```

Comment: Okay interesting! I will look into this approach. Thank you for the tips :)